# Joomla filter form in module for component, auto fill fields

Tags: forms, model-view-controller, joomla, module, components

I need to move custom component filter form from component view in to module.

In module I load form stucture from xml:

```
$form = &JForm::getInstance('myform', JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_man/models/forms/filter_oferty.xml');
```

I catch posted vars and place them in state by:

```
if ($filters = $app->getUserStateFromRequest('com_man.oferty.filter', 'filter', array(), 'array'))
    foreach ($filters as $name => $value) $app->setUserState('filter.' . $name, $value);
```

I use:

```
<?php echo $form->getInput('search', 'filter'); ?>
```

to place fields in module, form works but I cannot make form to auto fill posted vars in fields after request. What do I miss? How Joomla sets those values?

Comment: Please ask your Joomla related question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) ;)

Answer (score 0):

If somebody needs it I found solution to make simple form in module:

**Load form form xml:**

```
$form = &JForm::getInstance('myform', JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_man/models/forms/filter_oferty.xml');
```

**Put field in html by:**

```
<?php echo $form->getInput('search', 'filter',$filters['search']); ?>
```

The third param is default view. Using state is not necessary.